# Full adder (FA) base 8(Octal)

Tags: proteus, adder

Please give me some help or tip about this question, I need to make a simulation of this on proteus:

" Using full adder(FA) design a adder for numbers in base 8(octal)

6(8) + 4(8) = 12(8)   "

[image: Here is which was my first solution]

As you can see I transfer this two numbers to binary, and then i get: 110+100=1010
Then, I resolve the table and get the simplify function like this:
[image]
Look that I get two function ( the adder and the carry out). So whats wrong with my posible solution?

P.D: Sorry for my bad vocabulary and orthography, this is cause the english is not my native language

Thanks.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution get closed. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new on this, thanks for the clarification. And I already edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Doing an octal adder is no different than any binary based adder, it's all just in how you group the digits.

Hex, with 4-bit groups:

```
4(base 16)    0100
6(base 16)    0110
              ----
A(base 16)    1010
```

Octal, with 3-bit groups:

```
4(base 8)    000 100
6(base 8)    000 110
             -------
12(base 8)   001 010
```

Exact same bit patterns (1010 vs 001 010).  Circuitry is exactly the same, just grouped differently.  You should be able to finish it from here (I'm not going to show you a circuit for a FA).

Comment: Thank you so much, I have the things more clear now, and I gonna post the solution when I got it.